# why this Floating point addition can be solved only by multiply all the figures by ten?

Tags: javascript, html, floating-point, precision, tofixed

Because of Floating point arithmetic in Javascript, i understand `0.2 + 0.1 = 0.30000000000000004` will be in Javascript, but i don't understand why only multiply the figures by 10 i.e. `let x = (0.2 * 10 + 0.1 * 10) / 10;`, then the problem can be solved.  Should be multiply by `10**10`, right?

```js
let y = (0.2 * 10 + 0.1 * 10) / 10;
document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = "0.2 + 0.1 = " + y;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p id="abc"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why should it be 10**10? I mean, you've got the evidence right there that 10 is the correct value.

Comment: "0.1" in Javascript exactly is 0.00011 0011 0011 0011... 0011, to make it becomes an integer, it should by multiply by something like 10**10, otherwise, there are still remaining figures..

Comment: Where does `10**10` come from?

Comment: `Because of Floating point arithmetic in Javascript,`  Just a heads up, this is not a Javascript thing, it's how computer store numbers. IEEE 754.  eg. lets try Rust for example -> `println!("{}", 0.1 + 0.2);`  = `0.30000000000000004`

Comment: No, i had read the above link already, because I read that therefore i ask this question, "0.1" in Javascript exactly is 0.00011 0011 0011 0011... 0011, to make it becomes an integer, it should by multiply by something like 10**10, otherwise, there are still remaining figures..

Comment: The decimal number 0.1 can't be exactly represented as binary number. It has infinite decimal digits. It's 0.0001100110011001101... It will never stop. You can't store the binary representation (IEEE 754) in memory. You always have rounding errors. 10\**10 and even 10**1000 won't solve the problem.

Comment: That's not what 0.1 looks like, also. It is a repeating fraction, but floating point values are biased by a power of 2, so 0.1 is represented as x*2^8, with x bein 1.0 + the repeating fraction mantissa.

Comment: Yes, "0.1" has infinite decimal digits, then why this floating addition can be solved simply by multiply all the figures by 10, not "10**10"? "10**10" can guarantee round up all the decimal figures to integer

Comment: `0.2 * 10` = `2`  ,  `0.1 * 10` = `1`   `2+1 = 3` <--- fits into integer..

Comment: It doesn't eliminate the problem. It reduces the rounding error. 0.1+0.2 has a bigger rounding error than (1+2)/10. (1+2)/10 is still not exactly 0.3 in memory.

Comment: 0.1*10 should not be equal to 1, should be something like 1.00000000XX0XXX in return in Javascript

Comment: But 0.1*10 is equal 1: https://jsfiddle.net/qkyaLvdp/ Programming language compilers and interpreters have optimizers. I assume 0.1*10 is calculated as 10/10.

Comment: @eric2023 [you can play around with floating point operations on this page.](http://weitz.de/ieee/) In binary floating point (IEEE754), 0.1 is a repeating fraction, and 10 is not. The result of the multiplication is the exact value 1 (well, exact as it can be; there is no repeating fraction part).

Comment: Also [this explanation is possibly useful](https://www.gamedeveloper.com/programming/in-depth-ieee-754-multiplication-and-addition).

Comment: [Also this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0ol63OXojc)

Answer (score 0):

When you multply by 10 the extra bits get rounded off, and this luckily ends up producing integers. But it's not always guaranteed, it just happens to work for these two numbers.

The proper solution is to use explicit rounding after multiplying by 10.

```js
let y = (Math.round(0.2 * 10) + Math.round(0.1 * 10)) / 10;
document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = "0.2 + 0.1 = " + y;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p id="abc"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Many thanks for your reply and help, but could you illustrate how the extra bits get rounded off and luckily ends up producing integers? 0.1 equal to 1.10011 *2exponent(-4), right? 10 equal to 1.01 * 2exponent(3)), right? how luckily ends up producing integers? Many thanks.

Comment: I'm not really sure I can explain it in detail.

Comment: Re “… ends up producing integers… just happens to work for these two numbers”: This is a rough draft of a proof: Let x be a number that is some integer k divided by 10. Converting x to floating-point produces x+e for some rounding error e ≤ ½ULP(x). When we multiply by 10, 10(x+e) is rounded to floating-point. It is 10x+10e, so k+10e. 10e ≤ 10•½ULP(x) = ½ULP(k). So 10x+10e is nearer k than any other floating-point value, so the result is k. Except ULP(10x) might not actually be 10 ULP(x) when x or 10x is near a binade transition, so those need to be considered separately, hence rough draft.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be mixing bases without specifying when you're using which one.  It also helps to know that an IEEE754 implementation will give correctly rounded operations after each operation.

As you pointed out, 0.1 can't be represented exactly as a binary fraction.  The nearest value (for a 64bit float) is:

```
0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

when you're saying "0.00011 0011 0011 0011... 0011" it would help to say that these are base-2 digits, not decimal digits.

When you say 0.1 * 10, you're actually asking for:

```
10 * 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625
```

and the computer does that exact calculation and then round that to the nearest representable float.  The other values near 1.0 (which can be represented accurately by a 64bit binary float) are:

```
0.99999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875
1.0000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625
```

These are both approx 1.7e-16 away from the number, while the error associated with choosing 1 is only ~0.5e-16. Hence the FPU should choose 1.

The same applies to 0.2, which gets rounded to exactly 2.

Unfortunately I don't think Javascript exposes many useful primitives to see what's going on, so I've been using Python as it's good for interactively exploring things like this.

```py
# arbitrary precision decimal
from decimal import Decimal as D

# see https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/nextafter
from math import inf, nextafter

print(D(0.1))
# => 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625

print(D(nextafter(1, inf)))
# => 1.0000000000000002220446049250313080847263336181640625

print(D(nextafter(1, -inf)))
# => 0.99999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875

print(D(nextafter(1, -inf)) - D(0.1)*10)
# => -1.665334536935156540423631668E-16
```

hopefully that gives you some idea of what's going on internally!

Comment: Julia Evans has a good article on this, see https://jvns.ca/blog/2023/02/08/why-does-0-1-plus-0-2-equal-0-30000000000000004/

Answer (score 0):

Well multiplying by any number as long as both numbers are then integers, can be operated on. 10 is just a great number for this because it's just powers of 10 that are needed to convert the decimal places  into the integer part. **The reason why getting rid of the decimal places is helpful is because binary can then better represent the number, for example 1/3 isn't represented as 0.333... because it's redundant. The same issues happen with binary happen but with different numbers due to it using powers of 2 and other methods of representing decimals and eventually it has to do something.** That is why 0.1 + 0.2 = 0.300...4. *I'm not necessarily sure why you would think 10^10 is supposed to be used, it might have to do with the 0.300...4 but the answer is most likely wrong with float-point answers so that's why the equation's terms are multiplied, not the answer, also more floating-point issues could occur leaving an even worse result.* Here is my function that I like to use to solve annoying arithmetic floating-point issues.

```
//z = 1 or 0 (+ or -)
function float_operator(x, y, z){
    const precision = Math.max((Number.isNaN(x) ? 0 : (x.toString().split(".")[1] || "").length),(Number.isNaN(y) ? 0 : (y.toString().split(".")[1] || "").length)) || 1;
    const multiplier = Math.pow(10, precision);
    const result = z === 1 ? (x * multiplier + y * multiplier) / multiplier : (x * multiplier - y * multiplier) / multiplier;
    return result;
}
//> float_operator(0.1, 0.2, 1)
//> 0.3
```